# vnc log using up all hard drive space on linux?

Tags: log-files, vnc

Got a really weird problem.

Im on centos/linux using VNC. I am running a mysql update thats pretty big, but not more than a few gig.

I restarted mysql server while doing the db upload because i realised i had made a mistake and needed to start again.

Now i have a 79 gig file in my VNC log directory (no idea why or where this came from). I deleted this log, I have a 200g hard drive. Now when i check the total space in the drive its saying i only have 2.4 gig free. I am wondering how this can be when i just deleted a 79 gig log file from the .vnc log directory? I deleted also from trash. Seems like a v strange problem. Would be great to know if this is a common thing and if there are any fixes for the space and also a way of stopping it from happening again.

Cheers for any helps

ke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the VNC process is still running, it may still hold the log file open, and it may even still be writing to it, and because of that the file has not been removed from your hard drive.

You need to restart the said VNC process, and the space should be returned to you.

Comment: awesome thanks for this, i thought maybe i wouldnt be able to log in due to not enough space, but will try , cheers again :)

Comment: Im still having problems with this, is there any way to turn logging off in VNC, it keeps eating around 80g of my hard drive - not sure why?